# Typo3 6.1 - Backend Login - Blank screen but source loaded

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have a strange issue regarding a Typo3-Installation (version 6.1). The frontend works fine, but the backend-login is blank (white screen). When I look into the source of the blank page, there is everything there, compared with a working 6.1-instance.
I know, a blank backend comes mostly from some PHP-Errors, but in this case I can't find any. The install-tool says, that everything is fine.
There are no javascript-errors in the blank login and I deleted the typo3-caches. I also tried with different browsers on different machines - still a blank page, but source is there.
Do you have any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version (6.2.17) solved that problem.